# POSIX semaphores function sem_post() doesn't wake sem_wait() problem

Tags: c++, c, posix, semaphore

I am creating a Process P and Process P has child C. Both Process create one thread each. And i want to synchronize both thread using semaphore.
Problem is that sem_post from child process thread doesn't wake up sem_wait of parent process thread.

```
sem_t sem;
void* th(void* arg){
    sem_wait(&sem);
    printf("DONE");
}
void* th1(void* arg){
    printf("%d",sem_post(&sem));
}
pthread_t id[2];
int main(){
    sem_init(&sem,2,1);
    sem_wait(&sem);
    pid_t id1 = fork();
    if(id1==0){
        pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,th,NULL);
        pthread_join(id[0],NULL);
    }
    else if(id1>0){ 
        pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,th1,NULL);
        pthread_join(id[1],NULL);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that the two threads run in different process contexts, are you? They are not using the same semaphore instances anymore.

Comment: Ok i got the point. 
I want child process thread to wake up parent process thread. What is the other method to do it.

Comment: You need to use a named semaphore or other IPC mechanism

Comment: You'll need some IPC mechanism. Maybe a pipe or ZMQ sockets can help to solve your problem.

Comment: another semaphore option to consider are the Sys V semaphores.

Comment: From "man sem_overview" on Lubuntu 18.04 - "POSIX semaphores come in two forms: named semaphores and unnamed semaphores."   also   "Two processes can operate  on  the  same  named  semaphore  by  passing the  same  name  to sem_open(3) (in each process). Note: the sem_open must be performed in each process.